# Firebase DocumentReference.update is deleting the document

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have flutter code that I have been using for a while that I use to perform crud operations on my firestore documents.  I have one situation where an update appears to be deleting a document.  I have put a breakpoint in my code just before the update and hold a reference to the document in the firestore console.  As soon as the update runs, the document is removed from firestore.  Does this make sense?  Is there any condition that would cause a document to be deleted when invoking a DocumentReference.update?  Here is a snippet of my code showing the update I am trying to perform:

```
Future<void> updateInMyCartIndicator(
      ShoppingListItem shoppingListItem) async {
    logger.d("FSShoppingListItemHelper:updateInMyCartIndicator - ENTRY");
    try {
      CollectionReference shoppingListItemCollection =
          FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('shopping_list_items');

      QuerySnapshot shoppingListQuery = await shoppingListItemCollection
          .where("id", isEqualTo: shoppingListItem.id)
          .get();
      final DocumentReference docRefShoppingListItem =
          shoppingListItemCollection.doc(shoppingListQuery.docs[0].id);
      await docRefShoppingListItem
          .update({'in_my_cart': shoppingListItem.inMyCart});
      logger.d(
          "FSShoppingListItemHelper:updateInMyCartIndicator - Update complete");
    } catch (e) {
      logger.d("FSShoppingListItemHelper:updateInMyCartIndicator - Exception");
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

Comment: *"Is there any condition that would cause a document to be deleted when invoking a DocumentReference.update?"* - no.  Are you using Cloud Functions triggers?

Comment: No...I am not....no triggers.

Comment: Do you have any other piece of code ? (Maybe you are deleting somewhere else). Please provide an example of what are you updating , what is updated and what elements are being deleted? Also please explain what your code does in order to understand better the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce this behavior and no matter how did I update a document (empty HashMap as argument, null fields, etc..) it was not getting deleted. As such the most likely scenario is that the document gets deleted somewhere else in your code, probably as an unintended side effect.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response.  I was able to get past this.  Honestly, all I did was kill the simulator and my ide and the deleting stopped.  I can’t explain why it was happening, but it has gone away.